# Add @Html.AntiForgeryToken() to all forms dynamically

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

Is there a possibility of adding `@Html.AntiForgeryToken()` to  all form tags in MVC dynamically instead of adding to all pages manually?

Answer (score 2):

You could create another form on your master pages that will ensure that AntiForgery cookie gets created (if it is absent from the client's browser) and that a hidden field exists in the DOM needed for its correlation.

```
<form id="__AjaxAntiForgeryForm" action="#" method="post">@Html.AntiForgeryToken()</form>
```

Then using either jQuery or Javascript you could intercept all form submission and then add the AntiForgeryToken value that is then accessed like below:

```
$('#__AjaxAntiForgeryForm input[name=__RequestVerificationToken]').val()
```

There are plenty of ways to intercept form submissions and I don't have time to write up a full test so you should test the code below before using it since it may have a bug. But you would probably want to define a class for forms that should be intercepted or hook into their ids. But your structure might look something like this:

```
$("#formid").submit(function(e){
e.preventDefault(); //prevent submit
var self = this;

  $('<input />').attr('type', 'hidden')
      .attr('name', "__RequestVerificationToken")
      .attr('value', $('#__AjaxAntiForgeryForm input[name=__RequestVerificationToken]').val())
      .appendTo('#formid');
self.submit();   })  });
```

Of course the problem with this solution is that the client needs to have JavaScript enabled, but in today's day-and-age that is a reasonable assumption to make. Another approach would be to create your own custom HtmlHelper instead of using the stock standard one that ships with MVC. But this JavaScript approach has the added benefit of being the foundation for adding AntiForgery support to your ajax Posts since you could then also add a JavaScript Function to the same master page:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    AddAntiForgeryToken = function (data) {
        data.__RequestVerificationToken = $('#__AjaxAntiForgeryForm input[name=__RequestVerificationToken]').val();
        return data;
    };
</script>
```

That means that in order to do Ajax Posts you can do the following:

```
$.ajax({
        url: '/YourTargetUrl',
        cache: false,
        type: "POST",
        data: AddAntiForgeryToken({ field1: value1, ..... fieldx: valuex }),
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (response) {
        },
        error: function (xhr, status, error) {               
        } });
```

Answer (score 1):

You could build your own Form HTML helper overload that does it automatically by copying what is in the source of [FormExtensions](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/System.Web.Mvc/Html/FormExtensions.cs) and adding the code to generate the anti forgery token.

```
public static class FormExtensions
{
    public static MvcForm BeginFormWithAntiForgeryToken(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string actionName, string controllerName, object routeValues, FormMethod method, object htmlAttributes)
    {
        return BeginFormWithAntiForgeryToken(htmlHelper, actionName, controllerName, new RouteValueDictionary(routeValues), method, HtmlHelper.AnonymousObjectToHtmlAttributes(htmlAttributes));
    }

    public static MvcForm BeginFormWithAntiForgeryToken(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string actionName, string controllerName, RouteValueDictionary routeValues, FormMethod method, IDictionary<string, object> htmlAttributes)
    {
        string formAction = UrlHelper.GenerateUrl(null /* routeName */, actionName, controllerName, routeValues, htmlHelper.RouteCollection, htmlHelper.ViewContext.RequestContext, true /* includeImplicitMvcValues */);
        return FormHelper(htmlHelper, formAction, method, htmlAttributes);
    }

    // TODO: Add additional overloads

    private static MvcForm FormHelper(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string formAction, FormMethod method, IDictionary<string, object> htmlAttributes)
    {
        TagBuilder tagBuilder = new TagBuilder("form");
        tagBuilder.MergeAttributes(htmlAttributes);
        // action is implicitly generated, so htmlAttributes take precedence.
        tagBuilder.MergeAttribute("action", formAction);
        // method is an explicit parameter, so it takes precedence over the htmlAttributes.
        tagBuilder.MergeAttribute("method", HtmlHelper.GetFormMethodString(method), true);

        bool traditionalJavascriptEnabled = htmlHelper.ViewContext.ClientValidationEnabled
                                            && !htmlHelper.ViewContext.UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled;

        if (traditionalJavascriptEnabled)
        {
            // forms must have an ID for client validation
            tagBuilder.GenerateId(htmlHelper.ViewContext.FormIdGenerator());
        }

        htmlHelper.ViewContext.Writer.Write(tagBuilder.ToString(TagRenderMode.StartTag));

        // THIS WAS ADDED: Write the anti-forgery token
        htmlHelper.ViewContext.Writer.Write(System.Web.Helpers.AntiForgery.GetHtml().ToString());

        MvcForm theForm = new MvcForm(htmlHelper.ViewContext);

        if (traditionalJavascriptEnabled)
        {
            htmlHelper.ViewContext.FormContext.FormId = tagBuilder.Attributes["id"];
        }

        return theForm;
    }
}
```

Then you just need to call your HTML helpers whenever you create a form.

```
@Html.BeginFormWithAntiForgeryToken("Edit", "User", new { id = 123 }, FormMethod.Post, null) {
    <!-- Add form elements here -->
}
```